# My first roll a dice python game

Tags: python-3.x, dice, game-loop

```
import random


def diceroll():
        num_dice = random.randint(1,6)
        print("You got " + str(num_dice) + "!")
diceroll()
def question():
    response = input("You want to roll again?\n")
        while response == "y":
        diceroll()
        response = input("You want to roll again?\n")   
    if response == "n":
        print("Thank you for playing! :) ")
        exit()
    while "y" or "n" not in response:
            response = input("Please answer with y or n!\n")
            while response == "y":
                diceroll()
                response = input("You want to roll again?\n")   
            if response == "n":
                print("Thank you for playing! :) ")
                exit()
question()
```

Is there any way i could make this code simpler and have the same functionality?I tryed another version without using classes but once i enter another character besides "y" or "n" the code ends.

```
import random

answer = "yes"

while answer in ["yes", "y"]:
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print("You rolled " + str(roll) + "!")
    answer = input("Would you like to roll again?\n")
if answer in ["n", "no"]:
    print("Thank you for playing!")
else :
    print("Please answer with yes or no!")
    answer = input("Would you like to roll again?\n")
```

Comment: Your first version isn't using classes.  It is using a function

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program exits after you enter anything besides "y" or "yes" is because that's what you took as the condition to stay inside the loop. Your program assumes that "staying inside the loop" means "playing the game", but when someone enters illegal input, they should also stay within the loop. The only reason for exiting would be to explicitly ask for it, by answering "n" or "no".

Thus:

```
import random

while answer not in ["no", "n"]:
    roll = random.randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled " + str(roll) + "!")
    answer = input("Would you like to roll again?\n")
    if answer not in ["yes", "y", "no", "n"]:
        print("Please answer with yes or no!")
        answer = input("Would you like to roll again?\n")

print("Thank you for playing!")
```